# Excel VBA - insert formula in a set of rows with variable reference directly or replacing a string for example "\=" with "="

Tags: vba, excel

I have the goal to write a formula in a set of rows. Some references in the formula have to change  each row.

I implemented the  following script:

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim formcolM As String
Dim temprng As String

For i = 0 To 100  
    formcolM = "NUMBERVALUE(IF(Q" & i & "=""Bedarf kum."";A" & i & ";IF(Q" & i & "=""Ist"";OFFSET(A" & i & ";-1;0);IF(Q" & i & "=""Lz."";OFFSET(A" & i & ";-2;0);IF(Q" & i & "=""Ist+Lz.-Bedarf"";OFFSET(A" & i & ";-3;0);)))))"
Let temprng = "M" & i
Range(temprng).Select
ActiveCell.Value = "\=" & formcolM
next i
```

With this script I am writing a string each row in my excel table at column M.

I noticed that if the formula hasn't the symbol "\" , you can find an error .

In order to avoid the error  I thought to leave the symbol "\" and to use a trick  deleting it after (because I don't know how to solve with R1C1 formula. I read some answers on Stackoverflow, but  unfortunately I did not understand   )

The replacing script after the for cycle:

```
Columns("M:M").Replace What:="\=", Replacement:="=", LookAt:=xlPart
```

The strange thing is that the macro doesn't delete it.
Infact when the script finishes , it seems that nothing happened, without errors. But if I want substitute "\=" with another symbol, for example "*", the replacing script works.

I did not understand if the problem is :

- the replace method  did not recognized the symbol "=" to search
- I cannot use the replace method  because the symbol "=" disturbs in some way , I don't know in what.

**OR**, is there another simplest way to get this task done?

Someone could help me in order to fix? I should have the formula working in the column M , automatically with vba (not with another formula in the excel sheet)  .

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Change the `;` to `,` and insert the formula.  VBA is US-EN centric and the formulas must be placed in that format.

Comment: are you suggesting me not to use replacing script ,  deleting "\" from the formula directly?

Comment: `ActiveCell.Formula = "= NUMBERVALUE(IF(Q" & i & "=""Bedarf kum."",A" & i & ",IF(Q" & i & "=""Ist"",OFFSET(A" & i & ",-1,0),IF(Q" & i & "=""Lz."",OFFSET(A" & i & ",-2,0),IF(Q" & i & "=""Ist+Lz.-Bedarf"",OFFSET(A" & i & ",-3,0),)))))"`  I may have missed a `;`  make sure they are all `,`

Comment: I am using  italian version in excel. The formula that now I am using is : **NUMERO.VALORE(SE(Q" & i & "=""Bedarf kum."";A" & i & ";SE(Q" & i & "=""Ist"";SCARTO(A" & i & ";-1;0);SE(Q" & i & "=""Lz."";SCARTO(A" & i & ";-2;0);SE(Q" & i & "=""Ist+Lz.-Bedarf"";SCARTO(A" & i & ";-3;0);)))))**

Comment: Also this needs to start at at least Row 4: `For i = 4 to 100` as you are trying to offset up 3 rows, if you start at 0; 1. there is no row 0. 2. the last offset would reference row -3 and there is no row -3.

Comment: the formula that you see in the question above  is the translation using the tool in the link  [link](  https://en.excel-translator.de/translator/)

Comment: Also get rid of the word `Let` it is not used in vba.  IF that is the formula then use `Range("M" & i).FormulaLocal = "= NUMERO.VALORE(SE(Q" & i & "=""Bedarf kum."";A" & i & ";SE(Q" & i & "=""Ist"";SCARTO(A" & i & ";-1;0);SE(Q" & i & "=""Lz."";SCARTO(A" & i & ";-2;0);SE(Q" & i & "=""Ist+Lz.-Bedarf"";SCARTO(A" & i & ";-3;0);)))))"` Just this one line

Comment: yes, I simplified the script. Actually it starts from row number 4. I forgot  to change. sorry.  
But the problem remains :(

Comment: now I check  your correction for the " one line command"

Comment: It works! I had to use "FormulaLocal" command. We can close the topic . really thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can apply the formula directly.  The issue is that vba is very US-EN Centric and all formula when using the `.Formula` needs to be in that format.

Also since your formula refers to values in a row 3 above the one in which it is put we need to start the loop at `4` not `0`.  There is no row `0`

There are two ways, in US-En format with English functions and `,` as the deliminator using `.Formula`:

```
Dim i As Integer

For i = 4 To 100
    Range("M" & i).Formula = "=NUMBERVALUE(IF(Q" & i & "=""Bedarf kum."",A" & i & ",IF(Q" & i & "=""Ist"",OFFSET(A" & i & ",-1,0),IF(Q" & i & "=""Lz."",OFFSET(A" & i & ",-2,0),IF(Q" & i & "=""Ist+Lz.-Bedarf"",OFFSET(A" & i & ",-3,0),)))))"
Next i
```

Or using `.FormulaLocal` and the formula as you would write it in your native tongue.

```
Dim i As Integer

For i = 4 To 100
    Range("M" & i).FormulaLocal = "=NUMERO.VALORE(SE(Q" & i & "=""Bedarf kum."";A" & i & ";SE(Q" & i & "=""Ist"";SCARTO(A" & i & ";-1;0);SE(Q" & i & "=""Lz."";SCARTO(A" & i & ";-2;0);SE(Q" & i & "=""Ist+Lz.-Bedarf"";SCARTO(A" & i & ";-3;0);)))))"
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

By the time I got this worked out, Scott already had an answer. I just wanted to post your original code modified to work. I would suggest his method.

```
Sub TestScript()

Dim i As Integer
Dim formcolM As String
Dim temprng As String

For i = 4 To 100
formcolM = "NUMBERVALUE(IF(Q" & i & "=" & "Bedarf kum." & ";A" & i & ";IF(Q" & i & "=" & "Ist" & ";OFFSET(A" & i & ";-1;0);IF(Q" & i & "=" & "Lz." & ";OFFSET(A" & i & ";-2;0);IF(Q" & i & "=" & "Ist+Lz.-Bedarf" & ";OFFSET(A" & i & ";-3;0);)))))"
temprng = "M" & i
Sheets("Sheet1").Range(temprng).Select
ActiveCell.Value = " = " & formcolM
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: This method does not work, because it writes strings that they are not formula. Infact if you check, deleting the empty spaces ( from " = "to "=" )  you will see a runtime error '1004'  . But thank you for your help :)

Comment: That's odd, I got it to work just fine with no errors. I reformatted the "formcolM" line, which had the quote marks out of place. "Let" was not necessary. In my test spreadsheet, it inserted the formula in each cell correctly. I used "option explicit" to test. Regards